# How can i remove this white lines from ToolbarPosition.custom?

Tags: flutter, dart, html-editor

I'am working on a task and I used HtmlEditor package,

package https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced

I want to remove this white line under textfield.

[image]

```
 HtmlEditor(
            controller: notifier.titleController,
            htmlEditorOptions: HtmlEditorOptions(
                hint: 'Title',
                shouldEnsureVisible: true,
                androidUseHybridComposition: false,
                autoAdjustHeight: true),
            htmlToolbarOptions: HtmlToolbarOptions(
              toolbarPosition: ToolbarPosition.custom,
            ),
            callbacks: Callbacks(onInit: () {
              notifier.titleController.setFocus();
            }, onFocus: () {
              notifier.setFocus(true);
            }, onChangeContent: (val) {
              notifier.setHeight();
            }),
            otherOptions: OtherOptions(
                height: 60, decoration: BoxDecoration(color: noteColor)),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the package, and I'm assuming it's https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced , is it?

In any case a quick glance makes me think those are dividers and you can specify a custom one by changing the `separatorWidget` parameter, or remove them entirely by stating `renderSeparatorWidget: false`

Comment: That's the package, but 'renderSeparatorWidget: false' didn't work

Comment: @AdnanTurgayAydın ah, ok.  it was just a guess. Sorry I couldn't help. By the way are you sure those are part of the `HtmlEditor` it looks like they might be in between them